# python try multiple statements with same possible error

Tags: python

I'm trying to set some booleans based on whether or not an object has attributes:

```
try:
    att1 = myobj.att1
    att2 = myobj.att2
    att3 = myobj.att3
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

However, if `att1` is not present and throws an `AttributeError`, it won't try the other two. Must I loop (is there no way to do it in one `try` statement?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a try statement here. For example:

```
myobj = 10
names = ['att1', 'att2', 'att3', 'real']
results = dict((name, getattr(myobj, name, None)) for name in names)
#{'real': 10, 'att3': None, 'att2': None, 'att1': None}
```

Comment: Quite true. I like this getattr function.

Comment: Very few languages make meta programming as simple AND as clean as python.

Answer (score 3):

why not just do :

```
your_boolean = hasattr(obj, att1) or hasattr(obj, att2) or hasattr(obj, att3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this *only* to check whether some object has attributes? If so, use the built-in function [`hasattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr) (which in fact does the same test as you have implemented manually anyway.

---

Otherwise, you must loop.

If you think about the structure of the code, what you are really wanting is three try...except blocks -- after all, if exceptions returned flow to where they were raised after being processed, they wouldn't be very exceptional!

It would be pretty easy to write a loop, though:

```
atts = []
for attr in ("att1", "att2", "att3"):
    try:
        attrs.append(getattr(myobj, attr))
    except AttributeError:
        attrs.append[None]
att1, att2, att3 = atts
```

If you really want the attributes as local variables, you could even do:

```
for attr in ("att1", "att2", "att3"):
    try:
        locals()[attr] = getattr(myobj, attr)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Comment: Awesome. I wasn't testing for mere existence, so I guess I must loop. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Considering there is 2*2*2 possible existence combinations, why not have set?

```
set(attr for attr in ('att%i' for i in range(1,4)) if obj.hasattr(attr))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this also works:

```
try:
    (var1 and var2)
except NameError:
    ...
```

It will test all variables before making a decision.